# How do I respond to the user shaking an iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, iphone-sdk-3.0

Alright, so to get going with Objective-C (I'm usually just an HTML PhoneGap kinda guy), I made a simple Magic 8 ball app. I've got it right now so that when I touch the screen, the ball "shakes" and takes a random response and puts it in a label. What I want to do is when the iPhone itself is shaked, the text is updated too.

Here's my MainView.m:

```
#import "MainView.h"

@implementation MainView

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
  int rNumber = rand() % 26;
  switch (rNumber) {
                case 0:
                    shook.text = @"Never";
                    break;
            ....25 more entries.....
                default:
                    break;
           }
    }
 }

 - (IBAction)yesNo {
 [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.75];
 int rNumber = rand() % 26;
 switch (rNumber) {
  case 0:
   result.text = @"Never";
   break;
  ........
  default:
  break;
 }
 }

 @end
```

and my MainView.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface MainView : UIView <UIAccelerometerDelegate> {
     IBOutlet UILabel *result;
  IBOutlet UILabel *shook;
 }

 - (IBAction)yesNo;
 - (void)motionEnded;

 @end
```

Obviously there's an error in there, I know that much, but where?!

Comment: Why is it obvious that there's an error in there?

Comment: Sleeping the main thread is a really bad idea. Why are you doing that? If you want to delay execution of some code, use `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` instead. You should also refactor your random-testing code into a separate method that's called from both places.

Comment: Is the app crashing? If so, what does the log say?

Comment: It's not crashing... the shake just isn't working. I'll change the sleeping to what you suggested.

Comment: possible duplicate of [motionBegan: Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342674/motionbegan-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to read the documentation in more depth to get to the bottom of this. Specifically the [iOS Event Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW2).

From that document there are a few things which I would suggest you try:

1. Override **canBecomeFirstResponder:** and return YES (as per Listing 4-1).
2. Override **viewDidAppear:animated:** to become the first responder (as per Listing 4-1).
3. Override both **motionBegan:withEvent:** and **motionCancelled:withEvent:** as they do this in the example which may be because the framework is testing your view controller class to see if it responds to these selectors (as per Listing 4-2).

Look at the [UIResponder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (from which UIViewController inherits) for more detail on the methods you are overriding.

As someone who came from a Microsoft / VB / .NET and Android / Java background to Cocoa / Objective-C programming I would strongly suggest you invest the time in reading the documentation. Initially the Apple documents seem impenetrable but they're actually pretty good!

I hope that helps.