# shaking iphone in 4.0+

Tags: iphone, ios4, accelerometer, shake

How do I use shake-events in iOS 4.0+? I tested this solution but isn't working in 4.1. Is it possible that something changed or am I doing someting wrong? [motionBegan: Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342674/motionbegan-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this SO question [How do I detect when someone shakes an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone) 
The main trick is that you need to have some UIView (not view controller) that you want as firstResponder to receive the shake event messages. Here's the code that you can use in any UIView to get shake events:

```
@implementation ShakingView

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ( event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake )
    {
        // Put in code here to handle shake
    }

    if ( [super respondsToSelector:@selector(motionEnded:withEvent:)] )
        [super motionEnded:motion withEvent:event];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{ return YES; }

@end
```

You can easily transform any UIView (even system views) into a view that can get the shake event simply by subclassing the view with only these methods (and then selecting this new type instead of the base type in IB, or using it when allocating a view).

In the view controller, you want to set this view to become first responder:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [shakeView becomeFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [shakeView resignFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Don't forget that if you have other views that become first responder from user actions (like a search bar or text entry field) you'll also need to restore the shaking view first responder status when the other view resigns!

This method works even if you set applicationSupportsShakeToEdit to NO.

Comment: Infact i had a UIViewController Class.. Is there any way to have my UIVIewController became a UIView without re-coding evrythinG?

Comment: Well... A UIViewController has a view -- something like `myViewController.view` will get you its view.