# xcode ios 6 shake motion calls IBaction from previous view

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ios6, motion-detection

I'm a bit new to app development. In a viewController ( VPviewController ) i have the following code:

```
- (void) motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake){       
        [self startGame:nil];
    }   
}
```

In a different viewController ( VPgameViewController ) i have a different MotionShake event:

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if(event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake){
        if(count < 3 ){

            [self changeText:nil];
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1016);
            count++;

         }else{

            count = 0;
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1024);
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
            VPpoepViewController *shit = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PoepViewController"];
           shit.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
           [self presentViewController:shit animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

When i'm in the VPgameView and i shake the Iphone it's also calling the startGame function which is in a different viewController shake event.

How can i stop this?

Comment: Maybe this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342674/motionbegan-not-working) helps

Comment: In both views i have can become first responder and resign first responder. But that's not helping.

Comment: Do you want to detect the motion in Xcode or in iOS? If the latter, please don't confuse iOS with Xcode. One doesn't need Xcode for writing iOS applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have to unsubscribe your `VPViewController` from receiving the shake event notifications in its `viewWillDisappear:` function.

Generally, if you want your viewController to receive certain event notifications only when visible you should subscribe to the notification in the `viewWillAppear:` function and unsubscribe in the `viewWillDisappear:` function.

Comment: What is the best way to do this?

Comment: To control if a viewController responds to a shake gesture you should introduce a `BOOL respondsToShakeGesture` class variable for the `viewController`. In the `motionBegan` and `motionEnded` functions return immediately if this bool value is false. Finally, in the `viewWillAppear:` function set the bool value to true and in the `viewWillDisappear:` function set the bool value to false.